# Ng-model does not update view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have searched thoroughly everywhere and can't seem to find the solution to my problem.
I am trying to make a form to fill in to create new task object onto projects on the website like a scrum backlog or something in Angular and angular-ui.

I use Angular-UI for typeahead functionality for when adding team members to a task, so available members on a project pop-up. I have seen guys with similar problems, but nothing seems to solve it for me. Below is the HTML and the controller. Sorry for the long markup, but I suspect it has to do something with nesting the controllers and mixing the scopes, so I'm including everything relevant.

```
<div ng-controller="SubmitCreateTaskController">
<div class="modal fade" id="taskModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    <span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">New Task</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">           
                <form role="form" method="post" name="create-task">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="taskname">Task Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="taskname" ng-model="taskForm.taskName" placeholder="Task Name">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="taskdesc">Description</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="taskdesc" size="3" ng-model="taskForm.taskDescription" placeholder="Enter a short description here..." rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="assigneddate">Assigned Date</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="assigneddate" ng-model="taskForm.assignedDate">
                    </div>
```

```
                    <div ng-controller="TypeAheadController">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="contributors">Add Contributors</label>
                            <input id="contributors" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="contrib.selected" typeahead="member for member in contrib.stream_members | filter:$viewValue"
                            typeahead-editable="false" typeahead-on-select="contrib.onSelect($item)">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="users">Contributors:</label>

                            <textarea class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="users" ng-model="contrib.entered" rows="1"></textarea>

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="taskcomments">Comments</label>
                        <textarea class="form-control" id="taskcomments" ng-model="taskForm.comment" placeholder="Comments" rows="2"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="taskForm.submit()">Add Task</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>  

                </form>      
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controllers:

```
.controller('SubmitCreateTaskController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.taskForm = {};
$scope.taskForm.taskName = '';
$scope.taskForm.taskDescription = '';
$scope.taskForm.assignedDate = new Date();
$scope.taskForm.contributors = [];
$scope.taskForm.comment = '';

$scope.taskForm.submit = function(item, event) {
    var formData = {name: $scope.taskForm.taskName,
                    description: $scope.taskForm.taskDescription,
                    status: 'open',
                    assigned: $scope.taskForm.assignedDate,
                    completed: null,
                    contributors: $scope.taskForm.contributors,
                    comments: [{body: $scope.taskForm.comment,
                                user: 'RACHE User',
                                date: new Date()
                                }]
                    };

    var postURL = '../create_task/' + $scope.stream_name;

    $http.post(postURL, formData)
    .success(function(){
        taskForm = {}; // empty the form of previous input values
        alert('New Task Created for ' + $scope.stream_name);
    })
    .error(function(res) {
        alert(res.data);
    });
};
}])
.controller('TypeAheadController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.contrib = {};
$scope.contrib.selected = '';
$scope.contrib.stream_members = undefined;
$scope.contrib.entered = [];

$http.get('/stream_members/' + $scope.stream_name)
.then(function(res) {
    $scope.contrib.stream_members = res.data.stream_members;
});

$scope.contrib.onSelect = function($item) {

    $scope.contrib.selected = '';

    $scope.contrib.entered.push($item);
    console.log($scope.contrib.entered);
};
```

This last bit is the important part in 'TypeAheadController'. I am trying to add the poped-up team members to a textarea just below which would be sent to the DB later. That is why I have bound the actual typeahead input box to 'contrib.select' and the "display/post" box to 'contrib.entered', so the search can be continued after adding one member, the search box is cleared, selected member is added to box below, new search can begin. In the mark up I call the last (onSelect) function in the typeahead-on-select callback. This so that I can clear the input box and another member can be easily added without deleting manually. IN this function the entered member should be appended to the array that is bound to below "display/post" box. This happens, since the console log shows good value, the search/input field gets cleared, so the function gets called as well.

The view does not get updated with the updated array bound to display box however. I have tried EVERYTHING. I have googled around and found it here that dot notation needs to be used as Angular can't update with primitives, but this hasn't helped either.

Everything works fine, the logic is good, values are good when I print them out, pop-up works and clears up as expected, but The damn textarea under it does not get updated.

Any suggestions? I have been stuck on this for almost a day now and I am really frustrated by this. I would be ever so greatfull for any help!
Thanks guys in advance!

Comment: Try to isolate your problem. Maybe you want to try to reproduce it in a Plnkr.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Textareas don't use the ng-value as their value is contained within the tag. Remove the ng-model and put the value between the tags.

```
  <textarea class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="users" rows="1">{{contrib.entered}}</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I have actually tried changing that tag to an <input> because I was suspicious of the <textarea>, but I'm guessing that doesn't work that way either?
Anyway, this solved my problem. I'm not going mental I'm just tired, always good to know :)

Thank you again kind stranger!

Comment: An input would work properly that but then you wouldn't be able to have multiple lines which I would guess is what you want. I implemented something like this but used an ng-repeat in a DIV below the entry so the added items appeared as a list rather than a comma separated list.

Comment: Cool idea, now that the main logic works, I might look into other possibilities as the textarea displaying the array with angle brackets n all is uuuugly.

Comment: If your textarea inside a FORM you can then use ng-model="form.somevalue" and that will properly bind the value as the user types it in. Just FYI

Comment: Not sure why this has a -1. As stated above this is absolutely true. I have a plnkr that shows it. If you put the textarea inside a FORM then it works differently, but that is not how the problem was stated

Answer (score 0):

Textarea do use the value attribute, your code isn't working because contrib. entered isn't between the tags, but because you can not bind the textarea to an array (it needs to bind to a string).

look at this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PTHqEGCNlXORf7CHuyFI?p=preview), if you do this in your html:

```
<textarea class="form-control" disabled="disabled" id="users" rows="1" ng-model="contrib.enteredString"></textarea>
```

and add this line at the end of your typeahead controller:

```
 $scope.contrib.enteredString = $scope.contrib.entered.toString();
```

then the text area will update